# Android weird black videoview + errors on real world device, not in emulator

Tags: android, video, android-emulator, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

So, I have an app that I'm trying to get to loop a bunch of video portraits at the bottom. It works perfectly on the emulator (Android 4.1) and seemed to work on my phone (7.1).

On the device I need to deploy the app to (an old android 4.0 TV box) the videos appear black, or start showing something and then go to black shortly after.

I tried an emulator of 4.0 and it seems to  be doing the same thing, but I can't figure out why and searches for the error codes it's shooting out don't pull up anything.

It loops through all the portraits and creates video views like this:
`

```
                VideoView video = new VideoView(context);

                boolean failure = false;

                Log.d("videoPlayer", "Playing video: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/reviews/" + localPortraits[i]);
                video.setVideoPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/reviews/" + localPortraits[i]);

                video.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener(){@Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer nmp, int what, int extra){
                    Log.d("MediaPlayer", "CAUGHT ERROR. ReDownload");
                    badMovie(nmp.toString());
                    return true;
                }
                });

                    video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {



                            mp.start();
                            mp.setLooping(true);

                        }
                    });


                frame.addView(video);
            }`
```

And again, running in the 4.1 emulator it works beautifully. When I put it on the 4.0 TV or 4.0 emulator, it shoots out this:
`W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (8004, 0)
I/MediaPlayer: Info (8004,0)
W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (8004, 0)
I/MediaPlayer: Info (8004,0)
W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (8004, 0)
I/MediaPlayer: Info (8004,0)
I/VideoView: MediaPlayer:AMLOGIC_PLAYER Prepared
D/MediaPlayer: getMetadata
I/VideoView: Layout changed,left=3 top=3 right=80 bottom=140
I/VideoView: Layout changed,oldLeft=3 oldTop=3 oldRight=81 oldBottom=140
I/VideoView: .left=3.top=3.right=80.bottom=140.oldLeft=3.oldTop=3.oldRight=81.oldBottom=140.Rotation=0
I/VideoView: MediaPlayer:AMLOGIC_PLAYER Prepared
D/MediaPlayer: getMetadata
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -33554484)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1)
I/VideoView: MediaPlayer:AMLOGIC_PLAYER Prepared
D/MediaPlayer: getMetadata
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -33554484)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1)`

Plus a ton more along the same lines.

What am I doing wrong that it won't  run on Android 4.0?